# Different containers using margin-top

Tags: html, css, css-position

If I'm trying to position the text using `margin-top` all the other contents in the page are moving too, but if I move the image using `margin-top` only the image moves.

The image and the text are in different containers and have different class names too. Please help me figure this out I have a project due tomorrow.

I'm trying to replicate this design
https://www.figma.com/file/lKiNPZPWbCFo90bFyIKJeI/Portfolio-2?node-id=0%3A1

```css
#img-protect {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 40%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 18%;
}

.head-title {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #20c20e;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!--Home-->
<div class="head-title">
  <p>Hello,</p>
</div>
<div class="head-subtitle">
  <p>I'M ANONYMOUS</p>

<div class="buttons">
  <a href="#contact">HIRE ME</a>
  <a href="#">KNOW MORE</a>
  <a href="#">LET'S TALK</a>
</div>
<div class="let-me-protect-you">
  <img id="img-protect" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500?text=Let-me-protect-you">
</div>
```

Here is my html code

Comment: I don't know if that is your problem but it looks like you have not closed `.head-subtitle` after your `<p>` element which means that everything below is in `.head-subtitle`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor I already made you

Comment: @mplungjan I don't know if that was a good idea to add this `</div>` because this might actually be his problem.